# Line break issue when export data from gridview to excelsheet in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel

I have implemented export data from GridView to excelsheet functionality in .net application.

and result coming in the following format which is wrong:

[image]

but result should be in the following format:

[image]

column in gridview :

FirstName,

LastName,

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="List of Answers" >
    <headerstyle cssclass="headingtext" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblAnswer" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"List") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <itemstyle cssclass="cells" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and text coming from database for 3r column is:

```
"Q1:No<br/>Chair<br/>Desk<br/>Monitor<br/>Keyboard<br/><br/>"
```

row generated in excel sheet should be single according to result set.
Expected result should be as shown in second image.
How can we resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution.I have to put the following lines in style sheet.

```
br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work using a css stylesheet, but putting the style inline worked `<br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;" />`

Comment: worked with inline style. didn't work with stylesheet solution. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1):

You data in your database has two HTML linebreaks (`<br />`) at the end, so the data in your Excel sheet has them as well. This is, in fact, correct behavior. If you don't want the line breaks in your Excel sheet, don't render them in your GridView, i.e., remove the `<br />` at the end of your data before binding it.

Comment: but i want result according to the posted image.is there any trick for displaying data as required.

Comment: @Sukhi: Yes. Remove the `<br />` before displaying the data. If you show your data binding code, I might be able to suggest some modification.

Comment: If i remove "<br/>" it will display in excel sheet as "Q1:NoChairDeskMonitorKeyboard" that i don't want.

Comment: @Heinzi, but if he removes the <br/>, how will the lines break? It seems the asker doesn't want all the values of "List of Answers" on the same line

Comment: @Suki, @Lea: I meant "removing the *trailing* `<br />`". Sorry, I thought that was clear from context.

Comment: @Suki: Once again: If you show me your data binding code (i.e. the code you use to create the data source for the form), I can make a concrete suggestion on *how* to remove the trailing `<br/>`s and create the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following link

http://aspalliance.com/518

```
br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
```

is the key.